# recyclerview textview click get post_id?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview like this:

```
Name
image
Publisher
post_id textview with ID value hidden
Like unlike(invisible)

Name
image
Publisher
post_id textview with ID value hidden
Like unlike(invivible)
...
```

When someone click in like, it will become invisible and the unlike textview will be visible.

The problem is, I need to pass the post id value to .PHP that this user want to like.

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private final Context context;

//List to store all posts
List<Posts> Posts;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<Posts> Post, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all
    this.Posts = Post;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    Posts post =  Posts.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    //Showing data on the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
    holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
    holder.textViewID.setText(post.getPid());
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Posts.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewPublisher;
    public TextView textViewID;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
        textViewID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        textViewName.setClickable(true);
        textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //
    }

}
}
```

So I have many likes and unlikes, many post_id values... how can I get the ID value in the same cardview that user has clicked in LIKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use callback design pattern.

**Create an interface**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        //view on which user clicked and the post_id for which you want to 
        //some specific action
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int post_id);
    }
```

**Now create an adapter like below**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    // ...

    /***** Creating OnItemClickListener *****/

    // Define listener member variable
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    // Define the method that allows the parent activity or fragment to define the listener
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvHometown;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            this.tvHometown = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
            // Setup the click listener
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Triggers click upwards to the adapter on click
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            // Assuming positionList contains list of post id's
                            int post_id = positionList.get(position);
                            listener.onItemClick(itemView, post_id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Set Adapter from activity or fragment

```
MyAdapter adapter = .....;
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int post_id) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, post_id + " was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome, if it helped you then please accept it as answer.

Comment: for sure! do you mind to give me an example in my real adapter? I have just edited my question with my full adapter code... I'm having some problems to know where and how to add this there... thank you again, friend!

Comment: You are not doing the steps which i explained in the answer. You can chat with me here - https://tlk.io/passiondroid

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in `onBindViewHolder()` as below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.getAdapterPosition(); //use this as index to get item in adapter list
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! could you give me more details about how can I call this onBindViewHolder? how can I use this?

Comment: `onBindViewHolder()` method should be implemented in your adapter class where you use the above `ViewHolder` class. Refer this https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html