# Get item position in a List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this to get a RecyclerView position in the click event:

```
int position  =   getAdapterPosition();
```

and this function to return list in a position:

```
 List<Posts> Posts;

    public Posts getItem(int position) {
        return Posts.get(position);
    }
```

in this Posts lists I have:

```
public String getPid() {
        return idp;
    }
```

what I'd like to know is how I get this idp value from the position I want.

my code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private final Context context;

    //List to store all posts
    List<Posts> Posts;

    public Posts getItem(int position) {
        return Posts.get(position);
    }

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<Posts> Post, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all
        this.Posts = Post;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        Posts post =  Posts.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Posts.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewName.setClickable(true);
            textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position  =   getAdapterPosition();

// what to do next?

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your previous answer did the exact thing you are asking for... What was the issue there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469494/recyclerview-textview-click-get-post-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm... seems straightforward...

```
int position  =   getAdapterPosition();
Post p = getItem(position);
```

---

Do you really need the position, though?

The ViewHolder can hold the Post...

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    // Data
    public Post post;
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
```

And

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    Posts post =  Posts.get(position); // or use getItem(position);
    holder.post = post;

    // You could even make a holder.position variable... your choice.
```

Then, just use `ViewHolder.this.post` from the onClick

Comment: thank you very much! if possible, can you please give me a better example about `ViewHolder.this.post` ? how can I get the id I want in a string? thank you again! @cricket_007

Comment: I would strongly suggest learning some Java... `String pid = ViewHolder.this.post.getPid()`

Comment: I would suggest not learning it via Android code. That's my main point.